# Hibernate Make a join to existing many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relational-database

I have a table that have a Many to One relationship to a Many to Many relationship. I would like to know how to represent that with Hibernate annotations, couldn't manage to find anything that could help me.

Here are my classes :

CompanyEntity.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TR_SOCIETES")
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    private String _id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="TR_SOCIETESCONTACTS",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="Societe")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="Contact")}

    )
    private Collection<ContactEntity> _contacts;
}
```

ContactEntity.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TR_CONTACTS")
public class ContactEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private String _id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "_contacts")
    private Collection<CompanyEntity> _companies;
}
```

Thoses tables are linked by the relation : `TR_SOCIETESCONTACTS`

And here is my problem. I have a table "`Imputation`" that must link to one `TR_SOCIETESCONTACTS` in order to reference a company and a contact but I can't manage to do it.

Do anyone have an idea?

Thank you :)

Comment: Imputation table has any relationship with other two tables???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either make a relation from `Imputation` to  `CompanyEntity` or `ContactEntity` if this meets your domain model ... or -and I think this is more realistic- you can make a new entity `CompanyContacts` which will map to `TR_SOCIETESCONTACTS` table, make a many to one relation to this entity from each of `CompanyEntity` and `ContactEntity` and `Imputation` .. this will also be  the only solution if you need to add any state fields to the `TR_SOCIETESCONTACTS` relation itself

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'm going to try that asap :)

Comment: just to know, will I still be able to recover all my companies and their contacts just by making a 
companyRepository.findAll()
Like I'm able now or will I have to find a different way? :)

Comment: actually I havent worked with spring repositories much, but if the same rules for JPA apply (and I think they must) , then you will get all companies, access the company contacts (in case the persistence context is still there because it will be loaded lazily by default) from it then the contacts from the company contacts